# How do I echo exclamation mark in PHP string?

Tags: php, string

Could you please advise how to handle exclamation character in PHP as parser throwing error . I would like to have exclamation character as part of string and use variable across my code

```
  <?php
    $teststr = ‘kannan!’;
    echo $teststr;
```

Comment: Stop using Microsoft Word to write your code for a start. [Here's a cool _free_ editor I'm savvy towards](https://atom.io/)!

Comment: What keyboard are you using? It's really quite hard on a standard US/UK keyboard to make those marks, unless you are using an auto-correct feature. Don't use backticks either - they mean something else in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `‘` or `’`. Use `'`. When declaring a string variable in PHP, you must use `'` or `"`. Don't mix and match either.

**GOOD**

```
$str = 'str';
$str = "str";
```

**BAD**

```
$str = 'str";
```

Comment: You should also explain why not.